# How to loop through files, extracting matrix chips, and then compiling all the chips into a new matrix

Tags: file, matlab, matrix, indexing, sequence

Let's say I have the files:

```
famcal.2012000000000000000000625502.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625502.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625502.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625502.stellar.nir

famcal.2012000000000000000000625503.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625503.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625503.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625503.stellar.nir

famcal.2012000000000000000000625504.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625504.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625504.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625504.stellar.nir

famcal.2012000000000000000000625505.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625505.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625505.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625505.stellar.nir

famcal.2012000000000000000000625506.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625506.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625506.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625506.stellar.nir

famcal.2012000000000000000000625507.stellar.blu
famcal.2012000000000000000000625507.stellar.grn
famcal.2012000000000000000000625507.stellar.red
famcal.2012000000000000000000625507.stellar.nir
```

I want to be able to use all of these files in this order, to generate a new matrix.

So essentially, a piece of code that could go through the order of:

```
625502
625503
625504
625505
625506
625507
```

and for each of these number sets do the order of:

```
blu
grn
red
nir
```

I'm using code at the moment that extracts small matrixs from each of these files and then i save them to new locations in a new matrix.  For example:

```
a = 2000;
star_block = repmat(a,[41,78]); %populates matrix with 2000
```

this creates a matrix filled with 2000.  I want to replace certain sections of this matrix with the outputs from the files above.

```
star_block(2:10,4:12) = 625502 blu
star_block(12:20,4:12) = 625502 grn
star_block(22:30,4:12) = 625502 red
star_block(32:40,4:12) = 625502 nir

star_block(2:10,17:25) = 625503 blu
star_block(12:20,17:25) = 625503 grn
star_block(22:30,17:25) = 625503 red
star_block(32:40,17:25) = 625503 nir

star_block(2:10,30:38) = 625504 blu
star_block(12:20,30:38) = 625504 grn
star_block(22:30,30:38) = 625504 red
star_block(32:40,30:38) = 625504 nir

star_block(2:10,43:51) = 625505 blu
star_block(12:20,43:51) = 625505 grn
star_block(22:30,43:51) = 625505 red
star_block(32:40,43:51) = 625505 nir

star_block(2:10,56:64) = 625506 blu
star_block(12:20,56:64) = 625506 grn
star_block(22:30,56:64) = 625506 red
star_block(32:40,56:64) = 625506 nir

star_block(2:10,69:77) = 625507 blu
star_block(12:20,69:77) = 625507 grn
star_block(22:30,69:77) = 625507 red
star_block(32:40,69:77) = 625507 nir
```

**EDIT:**

```
band_files = dir([star_path '/*.blu']);
for i=1:length(band_files)
    blue01 = band_files(1).name; 
    green01 = strrep(blue01, 'blu', 'grn');
    red01 = strrep(blue01, 'blu', 'red');
    nir01 = strrep(blue01, 'blu', 'nir');

    blue02 = band_files(2).name; 
    green02 = strrep(blue02, 'blu', 'grn');
    red02 = strrep(blue02, 'blu', 'red');
    nir02 = strrep(blue02, 'blu', 'nir');

    blue03 = band_files(3).name; 
    green03 = strrep(blue03, 'blu', 'grn');
    red03 = strrep(blue03, 'blu', 'red');
    nir03 = strrep(blue03, 'blu', 'nir');

    blue04 = band_files(4).name; 
    green04 = strrep(blue04, 'blu', 'grn');
    red04 = strrep(blue04, 'blu', 'red');
    nir04 = strrep(blue04, 'blu', 'nir');

    blue05 = band_files(5).name; 
    green05 = strrep(blue05, 'blu', 'grn');
    red05 = strrep(blue05, 'blu', 'red');
    nir05 = strrep(blue05, 'blu', 'nir');

    blue06 = band_files(6).name; 
    green06 = strrep(blue06, 'blu', 'grn');
    red06 = strrep(blue06, 'blu', 'red');
    nir06 = strrep(blue06, 'blu', 'nir'); 
end 

blue1 = [star_path '\' blue01];
green1 = [star_path '\' green01];
nir1 = [star_path '\' nir01];
red1 = [star_path '\' red01];

%blue
fid=fopen(blue1,'rb'); % opens the file for reading
fseek (fid, 800, -1);% Skip past header, which is 800 bytes long
blue = fread(fid, [3552,6536], '*uint16', 'ieee-be');%reads in and converts .RAS file
blue_chip = extract_region_fwd(blue);
star_block(2:10,4:12) = blue_chip;%inserts star chip into main matrix

%green
fid=fopen(green1,'rb'); % opens the file for reading
fseek (fid, 800, -1);% Skip past header, which is 800 bytes long
green = fread(fid, [3552,6536], '*uint16', 'ieee-be');%reads in and converts .RAS file
green_chip = extract_region_fwd(green);
star_block(12:20,4:12) = green_chip;%inserts star chip into main matrix

%red
fid=fopen(red1,'rb'); % opens the file for reading
fseek (fid, 800, -1);% Skip past header, which is 800 bytes long
red = fread(fid, [3552,6536], '*uint16', 'ieee-be');%reads in and converts .RAS file
red_chip = extract_region_fwd(red);
star_block(22:30,4:12) = red_chip;%inserts star chip into main matrix

%nir
fid=fopen(nir1,'rb'); % opens the file for reading
fseek (fid, 800, -1);% Skip past header, which is 800 bytes long
nir = fread(fid, [3552,6536], '*uint16', 'ieee-be');%reads in and converts .RAS file
nir_chip = extract_region_fwd(nir);
star_block(32:40,4:12) = nir_chip;%inserts star chip into main matrix
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate those numbers, but a more reliable method would be to use `dir` and then access the files through the returned struct:

```matlab
blu_files = dir('*.blu');
for i=1:length(blu_files)
  blu_file = blu_files(i).name;
  grn_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'grn');
  red_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'red');
  nir_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'nir');

  % load files ...   
end
```

#### Edit

Put identical procedures into functions.

Based on the code example you posted in the edit to the question, the following functions would make sense:

**apply_chips.m**

```
function [] = apply_chips(blue, bx, by, green, gx, gy, red, rx, ry, nir, nx, ny)
  %insert star chips into main matrix
  star_block(bx, by) = read_block(blue );  
  star_block(gx, gy) = read_block(green);
  star_block(rx, ry) = read_block(red  );
  star_block(nx, ny) = read_block(nir  );
```

**read_block.m**

```
function [block] = read_block(filename)
  fid = fopen(filename, 'rb');                          % opens the file for reading
  fseek(fid, 800, -1);                                  % Skip past header, which is 800 bytes long
  data = fread(fid, [3552,6536], '*uint16', 'ieee-be'); % reads in and converts .RAS file
  block = extract_region_fwd(data);
```

You should now be able to do:

```
ranges.blue.x  = { 2:10,  2:10,  2:10,  2:10,  2:10,  2:10};
ranges.blue.y  = { 4:12, 17:25, 30:38, 43:51, 56:64, 69:77};
ranges.green.x = {12:20, 12:20, 12:20, 12:20, 12:20, 12:20};
ranges.green.y = { 4:12, 17:25, 30:38, 43:51, 56:64, 69:77};
ranges.red.x   = {22:30, 22:30, 22:30, 22:30, 22:30, 22:30};
ranges.red.y   = { 4:12, 17:25, 30:38, 43:51, 56:64, 69:77};
ranges.nir.x   = {32:40, 32:40, 32:40, 32:40, 32:40, 32:40};
ranges.nir.y   = { 4:12, 17:25, 30:38, 43:51, 56:64, 69:77};

blu_files = dir('*.blu');
for i=1:length(blu_files)
  blu_file = blu_files(i).name;
  grn_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'grn');
  red_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'red');
  nir_file = strrep(blu_file, 'blu', 'nir');

  apply_chips([star_path '\' blu_file], ranges.blue.x{i} , ranges.blue.y{i} , ...
              [star_path '\' grn_file], ranges.green.x{i}, ranges.green.y{i}, ...
              [star_path '\' red_file], ranges.red.x{i}  , ranges.red.y{i}  , ...
              [star_path '\' nir_file], ranges.nir.x{i}  , ranges.nir.y{i}  , ...);

end
```

Comment: Unless there is a way to assign them a place for instance i have six .blu files. They will always be positions 1,5,9,13,17,21 in the directory and that is the order i need them used. The same applies to green (postions, 2,6,10,14,18,22).  this is assuming the directory is default sorted by name though.... and if this is the case then red and nir will need to be swapped.  Unless there is a way to pioritize file use by the last 6 digits of the middle section of the file name, for example 625502.

Comment: `*.blu` lexicographically expands to all the `blu` files, the other filenames come from the string replacement (`strrep`).

Comment: and then i can do seomthing along the lines of `blue_file1 = blue_files(1).name;` to get the first file and then replace with 2,3,4 etc to get the rest of the files and generate their variables?

Comment: Depending on what you need, you load each of the files inside the `for` loop and apply/process them and save the result before the next loop iteration.

Comment: using `blue_file1 = blue_files(1).name` i was able to access all 24 of the files in the directory and successfully apply them to my code. This works perfectly thank you. I changed the 1 to 2,3,4,5,6 inside the loop and generated teh variables this way.

Comment: See my edit, i wasnt sure how to apply it to my different matrix outputs which is why i hardcoded them

Comment: How will it keep track/know when to use the specific indexes that need to be assigned (noted in the first half of my original question)

Comment: The issue is, that I have 6 different sets of those indexes where i need to insert the 6 different sets of (blue,green,red,nir).  With what you posted, i will only be filling the four slots of the 24 that need to be filled.

Answer (score 0):

[This could help you](http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F)

This shows what you can do with arrays, but it shouldn't be too hard to take this and turn it into a matrix